# jQuery Autocomplete response return: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to create a function that will display a button when no result's are found by "Autocomplete".

**PHP**

```
echo json_encode($row_set);
```

**JS**

```
$( '#objNr' ).autocomplete({
    source: 'php/v.php',
    minLength: 2,
    response: function(event, ui) {
        // ui.content is the array that's about to be sent to the response callback.
        if (ui.content.length === 0) {
            $('#newTableBtn').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $("#newTableBtn").addClass('hidden');
        }
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

The search works just fine. I get results. But when I'm out of results I get this message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>       at HTMLInputElement.response

What's wrong?

**UPDATE PHP**

```
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $row['id'] = $i+1;
    $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}
echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data
```

**UPDATE JS**

```
response: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.content != null && ui.content.length < 1) {
            $('#newTableBtn').removeClass('hidden');
            console.log('if')
        } else {
            $("#newTableBtn").addClass('hidden');
            console.log('else')
        }
    },
```

This one clears the error message.. BUT the else case will go off whether it's a result or not...

Comment: It would be nice to see how `$row_set` is created. Maybe it's just an issue with the content of that variable, not having the correct keys

Comment: If you put a `console.log(ui)` before the `IF`, you should get an idea of what you are effectively receiving from the server. I suppose the issue originates in the variable creation; you have a json array of rows, but you do not have a `content` key in that array

Comment: Object
content
:
Array[153]
[0 … 99]
0
:
Object
id
:
1
label
:
"22133-01"
value
:
"22133-01"

Comment: So, i suppose that back in the php file you could write something like `json_encode(array('content' => $row_set))` to get an array indexed by the "content" index you are checking in the javascript.

Comment: That one did really mess things up ;) No list for result..and null of "label"...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132779/discussion-between-erenor-paz-and-bjorn-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long and nice discussion with @björn-c, we found out the problem resides in not having initalized the array `$row_set` before fetching the results. This way, the json_encode would encode the result `null` and the autocomplete would throw the error.

So, the fix is to put

```
$row_set = array();
```

before using it in the while loop that fetches results from the db.

And Voilà! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (ui.content != null && ui.content.length < 1) {
  $('#newTableBtn').removeClass('hidden');
} else {
  $("#newTableBtn").addClass('hidden');
}
```

If `ui.content` is null it will throw an exception if you're trying to get it's length property. Ensure that is not.

Comment: I did put in: `console.log('else')` in the else clause.. and else is printed both when i get result and when i'm not.. but the error disapeared ;)